# Access secured Webapi from another webapi/services with Azure AD

Tags: asp.net-web-api, azure-active-directory

My WebAPI is secured with Azure AD

```
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(Configuration, "AzureAd");
...
"AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "ClientId": "58ca819e-0e9b-4c72-9ae9-",
    "TenantId": "3a0cf09b-2952-4673-9ace-"
  },
...
[Authorize]
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
...
```

How to authenticate and access this WebAPI from another WebAPI in the background?

Answer (score 0):

We need to setup a application role in the secured WebApi:

[image]

Create new application registration for background WebAPI.

- Add a permission to secured WebAPI. In My API\Application permission, tick on role admin. Finally grant to default directory. [image]
- Create a client secret.

[image]

Here is the LINQpad script for testing:

```
async Task Main()
{
    var tennant= "3a0cf09b-";
    // background WebAPI
    var clientId="be7e77ba-";
    var clientSecret = "u9h7Q~izIQZkfJbiCwgxy";
    // secured WebApi
    var apiScope = "api://58ca819e-/.default";
    
    var token = await $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tennant}/oauth2/v2.0/token"
        .PostUrlEncodedAsync(new {
            client_id=clientId,
            scope= apiScope,
            client_secret=clientSecret,
            grant_type="client_credentials"
        }).ReceiveJson<MyClass>();
        
    token.Dump();

    var data = await "https://localhost:5001/WeatherForecast"
        .WithOAuthBearerToken(token.access_token)
        .GetStringAsync();      
    data.Dump();
}

class MyClass
{
    public string access_token{get;set;}
};
```